# Div After the First Image

Tags: jquery, css, blogger

i need some help, i was looking for a way to place a div after the first image in the post. the div which i want to place after the image is included dynamically and placed above the image, the image has a fixed width and height (640 x 350px). I'm using blogger platform for my blog.

i'm not good at explaining things, so that's why i've created a rough design What i want to accomplish.

Please have a look at this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbYrn.jpg

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having that prevents you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: so what is the problem, do you have some code already? If you know where the source of your image is just put <div class="someClass"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your dom

```
myp = $("#photo_gallery").prev().clone();
$("#photo_gallery").prev().remove()
$("#photo_gallery .separator:first").after(myp)
```

Comment: If the Image don't have a specific selector, and there are alot of images in the post, then what to do! and cant assign any class of ID

Comment: If you post ur html . I shall be able to assist you

Comment: @XeBii You need to post your code or people will have trouble helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the Super fast reply Bibin,

Comment: Here is the POST link ... http://goo.gl/0JTZR
There's a Ad after the Post Title and below the Ad there are images, what i want is that ad to be moved after the 1st image. the ad is dynamically added from blogger

Answer (score 0):

Select the first image, and place the element after that image ?

```
$('img:first').after('<div>Hello Kitty</div>');
```

Find first image inside another element:

```
$('img:first', '#postID').after('<div>Hello Kitty</div>');
```